# .htaccess internal rewrite with preserving query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, joomla2.5

i need to rewrite a url, preserve one query string for internal rewrite.
and another for display.

so this current url:

```
www.mysite.com/staff/teachers?id=37:john
```

needs to be internally rewritten to:

```
www.mysite.com/staff/teachers/37
```

not quite sure where to start, im trying this, but don't know how to access the number between "id=" and ":" to use for the  rewrite

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rewrite a URL "for display". All you can do is tell the browser to load a new URL. When the browser requests the new URL, the server has no way of knowing *why* it is being loaded (i.e. that it was the result of a previous redirect) so that new URL will need to include enough information to load the actual page.

In other words, you have to either:

- include the ID in the "pretty" URL, such as `www.mysite.com/staff/teachers/37-john`
- have your application look up the user based on their name in the internally rewritten URL, e.g. `www.mysite.com/staff/teachers?lookup_name=john`

Comment: ok, thanks. so assuming i want to just rewrite to www.mysite.com/staff/teachers/37 , how can this be done ?

Comment: Well, really you want to rewrite *from* that URL: remember that the input to the rewrites is what came from the browser, and the output is either what is being loaded, or a new URL which you are telling the browser to use instead. So you want to match `/staff/teachers/([0-9]+)` and use the captured `$1` in the query string; there are plenty of examples of that kind of simple rewrite online.

Comment: couldn't find an example that will show me how to keep the number only (between "?id=" and ":")

Comment: @buzibuzi That's simple, just match `?id=([0-9]+):(.*)`. But you have no `?id=` and `:` - that's the bit you're generating. Like I say, you need to start with what the browser is sending, which is `/staff/teachers/37`.

Comment: ok, if that url remained the same i would have no problem. problem is its generated by Joomla after upgrading from 1.5 to 2.5 and i want to  replace these url's